# AWS Cognito SSO integration with Twilio Flex

Tags: twilio, single-sign-on, amazon-cognito, twilio-flex

Related to this doc: https://www.twilio.com/docs/flex/admin-guide/setup/sso-configuration

Is it possible to integrate AWS Cognito with Twilio Flex for SSO configuration? Has anyone done this before?

Any feedback is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to make the connection.

1. Create a new application in AWS SSO
2. In application metaData apply:

   https://iam.twilio.com/v1/Accounts/ACxxx/saml2

   https://iam.twilio.com/v1/Accounts/ACxxx/saml2/metadata
3. In the attributes mapping add:
   [image: Atribute mapping]
4. Get the certificate (X.509) and SSO links in the configuration tab
5. In twilio flex single sign on option:
6. IDENTITY PROVIDER ISSUER and SINGLE SIGN-ON URL use AWS SSO sign-in URL found in AWS SSO
7. DEFAULT REDIRECT URL: https://flex.twilio.com/NAMEAPP (last part of login link, after twilio.com/)
8. TWILIO SSO URL :IAM.TWILIO.COM
9. Add the X.509 certificate found on AWS SSO

With this, you create a user in AWS SSO, add it to the app and the user can access flex